# Split Android app manifest file into several parts

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have an application with very complex manifest (src/main/AndroidManifest.xml). Is it possible to split it into several parts?

Desired result:

- AndroidManifest_general.xml for common data (permissions, meta-data, ...)
- AndroidManifest_content.xml for activities
- AndroidManifest_widgets.xml for widget providers and related things
- AndroidManifest_...

There is "Merge Multiple Manifest Files" article at Android Developers, but it doesn't say how to define multiple manifest for single application and the same flavor.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Note:
Android Gradle supports manifest.srcFile property, but it seems do not accept list of files...

Comment: You can have one manifest per flavor

Comment: you can create separate module, android studio create manifest for each module

Comment: Asked  1 year, 10 months ago and still no answer? (((( That's sad

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to have separated manifest for **one** module. In the following cases can you have multiple manifests:

**1. When you have two (or more) modules:** For example `app` and `instant app` or any other modules with a manifest.

**2. When you have multiple build types:** You can use `src/release/` and `src/debug/` that each one has a manifest. you can use this way when you want have temp features for debug apk (for example different name or icon)

Comment: Thanks. I know about different modules/flavors/build types, but looking for solution for a single module. I believe it's possible to merge 2 or more xml manifests with Gradle at compilation stage.